# sql find children from selection

Tags: sql

I've got following customers details table :

```
Cnmbr,  loc,group
10001       003
10003       015
10003   0001    
10003   0002    
10007       006
10009       003
10012       006
10012   0001    
etc
```

I would like to find all customers details , for the customers of group 003 and 015 (also their locations if they have one)

So in this example the result should be

```
Cnmbr,  loc,group
10001       003
10003       015
10003   0001    
10003   0002    
10009       003
```

**EDIT**

Tried it with this inner join , but this doesn't seem to work

```
select *
from customers tbl1
where tbl1.group = '003' or tbl.tbl.group = '015'
inner join customers tbl2 on tbl1.Cnmbr = tbl2.Cnmbr
   and tbl1.loc <> tbl2.loc
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Why are row 3 (10003   0001) and 4 (10003   0002) returned?

Comment: Jarlh , because line 2 , customer number 10003 , is in group 015 then all locations of customer number 10003 should apear in the result

Comment: DBMS : odbc connection to IBM iSeries from a Lotus Notes server

Comment: Your "inner join" is in the wrong place.  The "where" clause MUST appear AFTER any joins.  Your SQL doesn't work because you have the where clause BEFORE your joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM mytable AS t2
  WHERE t1.Cnmbr = t2.Cnmbr AND `group` IN ('003', '015'))
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b17ae/1)

Comment: Thank you Giorgos. I had to change ` group `in t2.group and then it worked for me. It seems my server doesn't understand the ``

Comment: @MarcJonkers Backticks '`' are used in MySQL as field name delimeters. I thought you are using MySQL when I posted the answer. Glad I was able to help you!